# how to change state without calling $stateChangeSuccess

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to change the url without reloading  `$stateChangeSuccess`. When an element exists it should change the state and scroll to the element. I am able to scroll but not able to change the state. Sorry for my poor English.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
  function(event, newUrl, oldUrl, fromState, fromParams) {

    var l = ($location.$$path).split("/");
    l.shift();
    var step = l[1];

    if (step != "step4") return

    var module = l[2];

    if (newUrl.data.elementExists(module)) {

        var el = document.getElementById("SECTION" + module.hashCode());
        ZCScrollComponents.scrollTo(ZCDocumentationContainer, el.offsetTop, 300, null);

        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go($location.$$path)
        return false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a doc for the `$state.go()`

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

And we can read about the **options** object and its setting **`notify`**

#### `go(to, params, options)`

> ...
>
> Options object. The options are:
>
> - location - `{boolean=true|string=}` - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string, must be "replace", which will update url and also replace last history record.
> - inherit - `{boolean=true}`, If true will inherit url parameters from current url.
> - relative - {object=$state.$current}, When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
> - notify - `{boolean=true}`, If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.
> - reload (v0.2.5) - `{boolean=false}`, If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search params.

So the answer is use the **`notify: false`**, because of:

> If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.